# Partially pivot data?

Tags: pivot, unpivot

This is probably an easy question for someone out there (fingers crossed!) I have a table that has data like this:

```
syr  dst  sch  category     iep ell section504  Hispanic  Asian White etc etc
1718 001  158  overallboys   18  9               25             72   
1718 001  158  overall girls  9  1       2       21          2  70
1718 001  158  LEP-boys       2                   9      
1718 001  158  LEP-girls      1  15              12          2   1
1718 001  158  TAG- boys                          1              1
1718 001  158  TAG- girls                         2              3
```

And it goes on for 143 more rows of data. If possible, I'd like to keep the structure of this table, but what I need is (using Argos) to "flatten" this data into one LOOOONG line of data for each school, exported into a csv for upload to the feds (Civil rights reporting). So the above data would look like this:

```
syr  dst  sch  overallboys_iep   overallboys_ell  overallboys_section504   overallboys_Hispanic  overallboys_Asian  overallboys_white  overallgirls_iep   overallgirls_ell  overallgirls_section504   overallgirls_Hispanic  overallgirls_Asian  overallgirls_White LEPboys_iep   LEPboys_ell  LEPboys_Section504  LEPboys_Hispanic  LEPboys_Asian  LEPboys_White
1819 001 158    18                9                                              25                                        72           9                    1                2
```

And on and on. Eventually reaching about 1600 columns (149 class/enrollment-type categories x 11 demographic categories.) Am I being a rube to think there is an "easy" way to pivot the category rows into columns without keying in every. single. one?

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((select ',' + QUOTENAME( c.ff_name) field                 
        FROM i5_school_profile_crdc_Fields c
        WHERE sort < 788
        ORDER BY sort
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

 set @query = 
'SELECT GETDATE() date_loaded, 1718 syr, p.dst,sch, ' + (@cols)+ ' from 
        (
            select dst, sch, value
                , ff_name  field
            from i5_school_profile_crdc_upload 
            WHERE dst = '+ :parm_DD_District.district + ' 


       ) x
        pivot 
        (
             max(value)
            for field in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '


exec(@query)
```

Because I was working in Argos, I simply used this as the report query and it worked as a csv report.